# Validating the column value in the vaadin 7 grid

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

I'm new to Vaadin Framework. Trying to validate the grid column by using `preCommit()` method of `grid.getEditorFieldGroup().addCommitHandler()`. When i validated the first time, the validation was successful and the error indication as well as error message shown successfully. But again if i save immediately, the respective value becomes null while reaching preCommit() method. How to solve this issue?

I have tried with secondary object. So i thought that this won't affect the source object. But this hasn't helped me.

```java
grid.getEditorFieldGroup().addCommitHandler(new FieldGroup.CommitHandler() {

    @Override
    public void preCommit(FieldGroup.CommitEvent commitEvent) throws
    FieldGroup.CommitException {
        BeanItem item = (BeanItem)
        commitEvent.getFieldBinder().getItemDataSource();
        MyClass qm = (MyClass) item.getBean();
        grid.getColumn("myColumn").
        setEditorField(generateMachineCode(qm.myColumnValue());
    }

    private Field << ? > generateMachineCode(String machineCode) {
        TextField editableTextFiled = new TextField();
        editableTextFiled.setEnabled(true);

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(machineCode) && !machineCode.equals("12345")) {
            editableTextFiled.addValidator(new StringLengthValidator("It must be 6 
                    characters ", 6, 6, false));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I overcome this issue by getting the entered new value from the column in the place of preCommit() method. Please refer below,

```
TextField nameField = (TextField) grid.getColumn("name").getEditorField();
nameField .getValue(); // new name.
```

I will set this new name to my source object each time. So, once the validation was successful. The field value remains same since we set it to an object.